# Asp.net & JQuery: Showing a Dialog Window when a Form fails validation

Tags: asp.net, validation, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I want to show a modal dialog/pop-up window when the user has not filled in a text field on the page, instead of using an error text field on the page.

If the required text field is filled in, I want the submit button to work as normal (aka call the onClick function), but if it's not filled in, I want a dialogue window/modal pop-up to show up stating that they need to fill in the specific field.

What's the best way of this?

I personally prefer using the jquery ui library over the ajax control toolkit modal popup if possible.

Comment: I think a way of intercepting a button click and performing js before the postback is what I'm looking for - user clicks button, js determines whether to cancel the normal functioning (the onclick function) or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that you have to do is to do the following.

1. Create a JS function that does the validation, display the dialog if it errors.  Have that function return true/false if validation is ok or fails.
2. On your button, add an "onClick" method to the attributes.  "javascript: return YourFunction();" and you should be set to go.

The return value of your method will prevent postback if returning false!

Comment: Did you mean onClientClick? How do I call the backend submit function after the js validation?

Comment: no, just do myButton.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "myjshere").  It will automatically do the postback as long as your function returns true.